# How to preserve the value of dynamically generated TextFormFields while calling SetState()

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I am trying to build a form in flutter. The problem is, whenever i select a radio button, the values entered in textFormFields is lost. How to preserve the values of textFormFields while calling setState() method in onChange method of RadioButton. The number of textFormFields is dynamic. Also, if i use initialValue property of TextFormField, the entire screen becomes white.

Answer (score 0):

Extract your radio button to a new stateful class. The set state widget in the new radio button class would not change your textfield state.